# Send mail with attachments from an app built with Corona on iOS 10.2.1

Tags: ios, iphone, email, coronasdk

I need to send an email with attachments from my app built with Corona SDK on an iOS device with 10.2.1.  I had at one time built a Corona app that had the ability to send an email with attachments and it worked just fine.  Now, as of iOS 10.2.1, it doesn't seem to work and I can't tell if it's because I'm writing the code wrong or if the `native.showPopup` is not compatible with iOS 10.2.1.

I am using Corona build 2017.3059.

Also, I have checked my device (an iPhone 6) with `native.canShowPopup( "mail" )` and it indicated that the mail pop up feature is available on the device.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- Function to handle button event
local function sendMail( event )
   if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
      if ( native.canShowPopup( "mail" ) ) then
         native.showAlert( "Alert!", "Mail IS available on this device", { "OK" } )
         local options =
         {
            to = { "john.doe@somewhere.com", "jane.doe@somewhere.com" },
            cc = { "john.smith@somewhere.com", "jane.smith@somewhere.com" },
            subject = "My High Score",
            isBodyHtml = true,
            body = "<html><body>I scored over <b>9000</b>!!! Can you do better?</body></html>"
         }
         native.showPopup( "mail", options )
      else
         native.showAlert( "Alert!", "Mail NOT available on this device", { "OK" } )
      end
   end
end

-- Create the widget
local mailButton = widget.newButton(
{
   label = "Mail",
   fontSize = 64,
   onRelease = sendMail, -- this is my function to send mail
   labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } },
   labelAlign = "center",
   emboss = false,
   shape = "roundedRect",
   width = 200,
   height = 100,
   cornerRadius = 13,
   fillColor = { default={1,0,0}, over={0,1,1} },
   strokeColor = { default={1,1,1}, over={1,1,1} },
   strokeWidth = 4
}
)

mailButton.x = display.contentCenterX
mailButton.y = display.contentCenterY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working.  There were actually two issues:

**1) The email accounts on my device were problematic for some reason.**

For some reason, I'm not sure why, I had to delete my email accounts and reinstate them and that seemed to solve the problem.  It was a pretty common configuration I feel like, I had two Gmail accounts installed on the Apple iOS Mail app.  But deleting them and reinstating them did the trick

**2) You can't trigger alert boxes before triggering an email**

Before my code would work properly, I had to get rid of the:

`native.showAlert( "Alert!", "Mail IS available on this device", { "OK" } )`

So the working code is:

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- Function to handle button event
local function sendMail( event )
   if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
      if ( native.canShowPopup( "mail" ) ) then
         local options =
         {
            to = { "john.doe@somewhere.com", "jane.doe@somewhere.com" },
            cc = { "john.smith@somewhere.com", "jane.smith@somewhere.com" },
            subject = "My High Score",
            isBodyHtml = true,
            body = "<html><body>I scored over <b>9000</b>!!! Can you do better?</body></html>"
         }
         native.showPopup( "mail", options )
      else
         native.showAlert( "Alert!", "Mail NOT available on this device", { "OK" } )
      end
   end
end

-- Create the widget
local mailButton = widget.newButton(
{
   label = "Mail",
   fontSize = 64,
   onRelease = sendMail, -- this is my function to send mail
   labelColor = { default={ 1, 1, 1 } },
   labelAlign = "center",
   emboss = false,
   shape = "roundedRect",
   width = 200,
   height = 100,
   cornerRadius = 13,
   fillColor = { default={1,0,0}, over={0,1,1} },
   strokeColor = { default={1,1,1}, over={1,1,1} },
   strokeWidth = 4
}
)

mailButton.x = display.contentCenterX
mailButton.y = display.contentCenterY
```